# Dell Inspiron 5520 fan always working

Tags: power-management, fan

I was trying to find a solution for my problem, but without any success. Namely, I decided to move to Ubuntu system (from windows 8) and I installed latest one for my laptop (12.04 LTS).

I installed graphic card, wireless update, everything. However I'm afraid that my card is not installed property because in detail there is written 'Graphic driver: unknown' even if I installed it.

My fan is always working and I don't know how to stop it or prevent. On windows 8 everything works without problems, fan stops etc. What could be my problem?

Comment: which of the two problems you want to solve? Please keep 1 problem per question. And if your fan is working is because something is heating up.

Comment: Perhaps the solution to your problem is to use 'i8kutils'.

Answer (score 0):

Most of times it could be about your graphic card gets warm and because your graphic card is integrated into your cpu the system thinks that cpu gets warm

install `mesa-utils` and `mesa-utils-extras` and reboot  , for installing use the following command-

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

it will work for Intel Graphic Cards

If you are having NVIDIA graphic card then use bumblebee because mesa and NVIDIA will conflict with each other for sure.. to install bumblebee use-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/testing
```

then for 12.04 and 13.04 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
```

otherwise  for 13.10 use-

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

If that doesnt work, try to

1. `Cleaning your laptop`- As might be its because of just that, stopping fan from running  properly.
2. `Update bios` - After updating it can perform good operations like increasing compatibility .That solved my issue.
3. `Update Kernel`

hope the very first suggestion will resolve your problem.