# Fan running constantly after installing ubuntu [dell inspiron 5520]

Tags: 13.10, dell, laptop, fan

i installed ubuntu 13.10 on my dell inspiron 5520 and this is my first experience with ubuntu or any OS other than windows..

`the system starts up normally and functions although it seems`to be slower than win 8.1 (thats not much of an issue though) but once the fan starts running it wont stop untill i shut down the laptop. this is the only major issue i have with ubuntu

Comment: Why 13.10 and not 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I would check would be the load of the system (as this is usually the case when the fan revs up), fire up a terminal and type:

```
uptime
```

To read more about the load values, see for example this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617500/understanding-load-average-vs-cpu-usage

If it seems high, you might also wanna dig deeper into the top command:

```
top
```

and even checking all the process, with

```
ps -aux
```

trying to pinpoint if there are applications running hot.

Comment: thanks but that doesnt seem to be the problem . i ran the uptime command and the following values came                                            14:38:49 up 3:51,  2 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.20, 0.19       that doesnt seem to be high

Comment: All right, what about checking the temperature sensonrs with lm-sensors: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto.

Comment: Related threads: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259778/fan-always-running-in-dell-inspiron-5520, http://askubuntu.com/questions/370652/dell-inspiron-5520-fan-always-working